# How can I prewarm laravel vapor lambda instances as well as the serverless db?

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I'm having difficulty pre-warming my deploys.  The first few minutes after a deploy produce a lot of request timeouts, followed by too many db connections, ... followed by stability.  If I pre-warm a bunch then it triggers the too many db connection errors ... so I guess I need to pre-scale both.  Anybody know how to do this in vapor.yaml or vapor web gui ... or aws as a last resort? (but I'd like to keep the infra config with the project repo)

Comment: Only warm up enough to not overwhelm your database, or scale the database up to accommodate your expected max.

Comment: @ceejayoz - yes, how do I pre-scale the db in vapor?

Comment: RDS has multiple options, from traditional hosted MySQL to an auto-scaling Postgres via Aurora. Scaling them up works differently in each.

Comment: @ceejayoz I assumed the vapor yaml directive would be the same for both - if it makes some difference I am on Aurora.  My preference is a vapor solution, but if I'm reading between your lines accurately - I think you're steering toward an AWS account config.  I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the vapor.yml solution I was hoping to reach, but I ended up going into aws and configuring more baseline db capacity.

aws console > rds > databases > MyDB
click "modify"
change the "capacity settings"